# Encounter error "IB API required" when IB API is installed

Tags: python, tws, ib-api

I am trying out this new python package ib_insync.

https://github.com/erdewit/ib_insync

I ran the python script below;

```
from ib_insync import *

ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, clientId=1)

contract = Forex('EURUSD')
bars = ib.reqHistoricalData(contract, endDateTime='', durationStr='30 D', barSizeSetting='1 hour', whatToShow='MIDPOINT', useRTH=True)

# convert to pandas dataframe:
df = util.df(bars)
print(df[['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close']])
```

I encountered the error `IB API from http://interactivebrokers.github.io is required`.

I have already installed IB API ver 9.73.06 under C:\TW_API folder. I am using Windows 10 and anaconda python v3.6 .

Here is a snapshot of my TWS API settings;

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. The problem was that ib-api python module was not installed into the python version that I am using

There is a README.md found in `C:\TW_API\source\pythonclient`
Following the instructions, I ran the following commands;

```
$ python setup.py bdist_wheel
$ python -m pip install --user --upgrade dist/ibapi-9.73.6-py3-none-any.whl
```

My python script runs normally without error now.

Comment: where did you run your commands?  I can't get it to work for me.  I tried the command line

Comment: @aiden From anaconda prompt, go to directory where setup.py is installed (eg. C:\TWS API\source\pythonclient\) and run from there

Answer (score 3):

After installing the TWS API, locate the folder "TWS API". In that folder, find the folder named "source", then the folder named "pythonclient".

Once you're in the folder "pythonclient", copy all the content in there and paste it into your working directory.

You should no longer get the `IB API from http://interactivebrokers.github.io is required` error again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general error that occurs when the Python interpreter can't find a module because its not listed in the PYTHONPATH environment variable. One option is to install the ibapi module as a Wheel. Or, if you are using an IDE such as PyCharm you can just right-click on the pythonclient folder in the project directory in the IDE and choose "Mark Directory as Source". This is mentioned in the [recorded IBKR Python API webinar](https://register.gotowebinar.com/register/5481173598715649281).

Since a Python API program is dependent on a specific version of the API, many users also like to use virtual environments (virtualenv) to organize version-specific dependencies of code rather than installing everything globally.

Answer (score 1):

For windows 10:
Maybe as of Feb 2022 none of the above-mentioned options works. Please, try the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\TWS_API\\source\\pythonclient")
import ibapi
```

The TWS API is installed in this folder: c:\TWS_API